# Mybatis returningHashMap

Tags: spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper, mybatis-sql

I am new to MyBatis. Could anyone help me to resolve this. Thank you.

I created a table named "CodeValue" with columns  like "Code","Value" etc. I am retrieving the columns "Code","Value" from the table using mybatis selectMap() method which should return HashMap with key "Code" and value "Value" as follows

```
<select id="getResults" parameterType="java.util.Map" resultType="java.util.HashMap">
   select "Code","Value" from "CodeValue"
</select

 Map<String, String> CodeValueMap = getSqlSession().selectMap("getResults", null, "Code");
```

I defined POJO as below

```
class CodeValue
{
  private String code;
  private String value;
  ....
  ...

  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getKey() {
    return "code";
  }


  public String getDefaultSortColumn() {
    return code;
  }


  public String getUniqueKey() {
    return code;
  }
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

}

when I run the code I am getting results like below

```
{CODE1={Value=A, Code=CODE1}, CODE2={Value=B, Code=CODE2}, CODE3={Value=C, Code=CODE3}, CODE4={Value=D, Code=CODE4}, CODE5={Value=E, Code=CODE5}, CODE6={Value=F, Code=CODE6}, CODE7={Value=G, Code=CODE7}}
```

but I want results as follows

```
{{CODE1=A},{CODE2=B},{CODE3=C},{CODE4=D},{CODE5=E},{CODE6=F},{CODE7=G}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

MyBatis may not be able to return a `Map` directly in the form you need.
But it is not so hard to convert the result.

If you call `selectList()` [1], MyBatis may return a list of `Map`s.

```
[{Value=A, Code=CODE1},
{Value=B, Code=CODE2},
{Value=C, Code=CODE3}]
```

And the below is an example code that performs the conversion.

```java
List<Map<String, Object>> maps = sqlSession.selectList("getResults");
Map<String, String> map = maps.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
    m -> (String) m.get("CODE"),
    m -> (String) m.get("VALUE")));

assertEquals("A", map.get("Code1"));
assertEquals("B", map.get("Code2"));
assertEquals("C", map.get("Code3"));
```

[1] `selectMap()` is a method for very specific usage.

Comment: Thank you very much Ave.  This works well for me. I really appreciate your help. Thank You.